# Server-side form validation weird error

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code for form processing :

```
$post = cleanpost($_POST, $db->link);

echo strlen($post['login']).' -- '.strlen($post['pass']); // for debug

if ((strlen($post['login']) < 3) || (strlen($post['pass'] < 7)))
{
    $page = new Page("subscribe");
    $page->assign("msg", "At least 3 characters for the login and 7 characters for the password");
}
```

The form successfully filters the stated cases (less then 3 chars for the login and less than 7 chars for the password) but sometimes I get filtered when I should pass : I tried to register with "asdf" // "asdfasdf" and I still get the message. As you can see, I have echoed my strlens, they say 4 and 8. I'm totally stuck here

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((strlen($post['login']) < 3) || (strlen($post['pass'] < 7)))
```

should be:

```
if ((strlen($post['login']) < 3) || (strlen($post['pass']) < 7))
```

Comment: how (strlen($post['pass'] < 7) can work? strlen($post['pass']) should be

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Why all the downvotes ? I upvoted and tried to validate but I have to wait 6 minutes. Thank you for your answer and sorry for the stupid question I just noticed my mistake, I've slept 5 hours in 3 days

Comment: Yes, parenthesis missing, edit your post, but the closing parenthesis for the second strlen was the right answer to my problem

Comment: @KiJéy - thanks for upvote. Basically it will work with this parenthesis placement. But you have understood my answer correctly, glad to help.